# Multithread DNS Query against specific DNS, domain and recordtype supporting Library

Tags: php, python, multithreading, dns

### Resolved, used adns with python bindings...

I have a scenario in which i have to do the following:

- Load a domain
- Load what record type is to be queried
- Load list of DNS
- Perform query, fetch results and display them.

I have tried this but its not multi threaded and even a single query takes about 3 seconds. I looked at ADNS, its python binding and http://www.catonmat.net/blog/asynchronous-dns-resolution , its much much faster than any other way but i still haven't found a way with ADNS Python bindings to query a specific DNS server instead of the ones used in resolv.conf.

What do you think? Is there a solution? Or should i launched each ADNS query in a chrooted environment with resolv.conf created the fly?

Oh and i would prefer it to be PHP/Python to easily include it in an appiication.

Answer (score 1):

If you do go with PHP for the client side and feed it with domains to query, you should consider [stream_select](http://php.net/stream_select) for working with many streams (each one a dns query) in a non-blocking way. Wez Furlong [explains it](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2005/may/guru-multiplexing) well.

Comment: To see a stream_select library in action checkout http://drupal.org/project/httprl. Should give you some ideas on how to accomplish what your trying to do.